# Display a loader when the page loads

Tags: javascript, preloader, pageload

How do I display a loader when the page loads and hide it when it is loaded?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.windowLoader').show().fadeOut(2000);
});
```

Displays the loader long after the page start loading and sometime the 2000 ms duration of the `fadeOut` event completed before the page has loaded.

Is there anyway to executed the display of the loader as soon as the DOM is ready and remain it visible until the page is loaded (not the images) and then hide the loader?

Answer (score 4):

Why not put the loader directly in the document and then on ready remove it using jQuery? E.G.

```
<div id="loading"></div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#loading").fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).remove(); // Optional if it's going to only be used once.
    });
});
```

Else, if you're doing other things within your `$(document).ready()` then `.fadeIn()` (/show/create) your loading bar at the top of the method, do your extensive code, and then at the bottom call the `.fadeOut()`

As kindly suggested if you're worried about people without JavaScript viewing the loading bar then also add the following:

```
<noscript>
    <style> #loading { display:none; } </style>
</noscript>
```

Comment: Although one drawback is that a minuscule proportion of visitors that have JS turned off will be stuck at the loading screen forever :P

Comment: I cannot remove it, I need it later time from other methods. I can hide it.

Comment: @TapasBose - Oh OK, well I just threw it in to represent that you should consider removing "one time" things.

Comment: @Terry - although if you're going to have a loading bar, presumably what it's loading is going to require JS! But yeh, good point well made.

Comment: @IanClark the document.ready fires long after page start loading. Is there any event which fires before it?

Comment: @TapasBose not as far as I'm aware - you tend to use `$(document).ready()` so that you know all your DOM elements have been created. If you create this element and put it at the top of your body perhaps that's not an issue. As in, try using it outside of a `.ready()` method but **only** if it doesn't rely on any elements to be loaded.

Comment: In all honesty, I have stopped catering for visitors with JS disabled... not good practice, but spending too much time for a non-JS compatible site can be tiring

Comment: @Terry Hah - yeh I suppose better to break on page 1 than on page 20 after the user is expecting it to work :P

Comment: @IanClark Lessening the agony, too, I'd say :) but yes, sometimes I have to fall back to the `<noscript>` method for compatibility or UX reasons.

Answer (score 0):

it should help
customize it according to your code

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            // calculate height
            var screen_ht = jQuery(window).height();
            var preloader_ht = 5;
            var padding = (screen_ht / 5) - preloader_ht;
            jQuery("#preloader").css("padding-top", padding + "px");


            // loading animation using script 

            function anim() {
                jQuery("#preloader_image").animate({ left: '1px' }, 2000,
                function () {
                    jQuery("#preloader_image"), animate({ left: '1px' }, 2000);
                }
                );
            }
            //anim();
        });
    function hide_preloader() {
    // To apply Fade Out Effect to the Preloader 
    jQuery("#preloader").fadeOut(1000);
    }
    </script>
<style>
    #preloader {background: #1c1c1c;position:fixed;left:0px; top:0px; width:100%; height:100%; text-align:center;color:#fff;z-index: 100000000;}
    #preloader div {width:228px;height:240px;margin:auto;padding:10px 0;text-align:center;overflow:hidden;}
    #preloader_image {width:228px;height:240px;position: relative;left:0px;top:-10px;}
</style>
</head>

<body id="home" onload="hide_preloader()">
    <div id="preloader">
        <div>
            <div id="preloader_image">
                <img src="loading.gif" style="position: absolute;bottom: 0;left: 35%;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```