# how to show loader in specific div of <body> only when page is loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have following html

```
<body>
<div class="menus"></div>
<div class="maincontent"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Now when the page loads I want to show div class menus and footer and until the page loads loader image in div maincontent. How am I to achieve this? I tried putting loader div inside maincontent and using `$(window).load(function(){})` but to no avail. Any idea and suggestions is welcome.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379677/display-a-loader-when-the-page-loads Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207740/display-ajax-loader-on-page-load

Answer (score 0):

This should be the initial HTML.

```
<body>
<div class="menus"></div>
<img src="ajaxloader.gif" class="loader" style="display:block"/>
<div class="maincontent" style="display:none">
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```

After this, you can hide the loader once the page loads and show the main content. If you are using Jquery, this can be done as follows

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.loader').hide();
$('.maincontent').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
$(".maincontent").fadeOut( "slow"); 
$(".menus,.footer").fadeIn("slow", function() {
     $(this).text("menu, footer"); 
}); 
});
```

After window loading,main content loading image hide and menu, footer shows

**[CheckFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeyashri/q4pdW/2/)**